# how to deduce function template argument from function return type?

Tags: c++, c++17

Example:

```
template<typename T>
T get() {
    return T{};
}

void test() {
    float f = get();//requires template argument; e.g. get<float>();
}
```

I understand that `float` can be converted to `double` or even `int`; is it possible to have `get<T>` instanciated automatically based on the requested return type? If so how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, template argument deduction from the return type works only for conversion operator templates:

```
struct A {
    template<typename T>
    operator T() {
        //...
    }
};

//...

// calls `operator T()` with `T == float` to convert the `A` temporary to `float`
float f = A{};
```

This can also be used to have `get` return the `A` object so that `float f = get();` syntax will work as well.
However, it is questionable whether using this mechanism as you intent is a good idea. There are quite a few caveats and can easily become difficult to follow. For example what happens in `auto f = get();`? What happens if there are multiple overloads of a function `g` in a call `g(get())`? Etc.

Instead move your type specifier to the template argument and you wont have to repeat yourself:

```
auto f = get<float>();
```

Comment: Right, `get()` can return an instance of `A` which is later converted.  But I think your  coworkers (if any) will hate you for doing this.  Also note that `operator T` does not have to be a template, you could write separate `operator double`, `operator int`, etc.